# How to use the python pypff library to find the start and end time of an event in the outlook calendar (*.pst)

Tags: python, outlook, appointment, pst, libpff

How to use the python `pypff` library to find the start and end time of an event in the outlook calendar (*.pst)?

Using my recursive function, I get access to calendar events as messages, and then I get all the attributes.

In the list of attributes with type `datetime` I get the time of creation, modification, etc. - I do not need them.

```
one message <pypff.message object at 0x0000021CC3698150>
    --  one_attr=client_submit_time   2024-01-23 02:25:38.495000 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    --  one_attr=creation_time        2024-01-23 02:25:18.160000 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    --  one_attr=delivery_time        2024-01-23 02:25:38.495000 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
    --  one_attr=modification_time    2024-01-23 09:34:04.661000 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Then, through record_sets, I get 8 more entries with datetime type, which have different entry_types.

```
entries record_set <pypff.record_set object at 0x0000021CC36080D0>
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 2, 25, 38, 495000) one_entry.entry_type=57
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 2, 25, 38, 495000) one_entry.entry_type=3590
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 2, 25, 18, 160000) one_entry.entry_type=12295
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 9, 34, 4, 661000) one_entry.entry_type=12296
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 6, 30) one_entry.entry_type=32772
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 9, 0) one_entry.entry_type=32773
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 6, 30) one_entry.entry_type=32774
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 9, 0) one_entry.entry_type=32775
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 2, 25, 38, 495000) one_entry.entry_type=32882
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 6, 30) one_entry.entry_type=32888
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(4501, 1, 1, 0, 0) one_entry.entry_type=32890
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 23, 6, 30) one_entry.entry_type=32942
   * one_entry.value_type=64 one_entry.data_as_datetime=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 24, 9, 0) one_entry.entry_type=32943
```

This is how the event is produced in Outlook itself:

[image: This is how the event is produced in Outlook itself]

```
def getID(f, level = 0, findAttr=None, ix=None):
    methods = dir(f)
    getAttr(f, skip_staff=True, findAttr=findAttr, skipEnum=False)
    enumses = []
    if 'record_sets' in methods:
        enumses.append(f.record_sets)
    if 'sub_folders' in methods:
        enumses.append(f.sub_folders)
    if 'sub_items' in methods:
        enumses.append(f.sub_items)
    if 'sub_messages' in methods:
        enumses.append(f.sub_messages)
    if 'entries' in methods:
        enumses.append(f.entries)
    if ('sub_messages' in methods) and (findAttr is not None):
        enumses.append(f.sub_messages)


    for idx0, one in enumerate(enumses):
        for idx, one2 in enumerate(one):
            getID(one2, findAttr=findAttr, level = level+1)
```

`

How to understand which entry_type corresponds to the beginning and end of an event in the calendar?

Or is there any other way to get the subject, Start, End of each event?

Comment: You’ll need to look up the property IDs for AppointmentStartWhole and AppointmentEndWhole. The actual entry type for these is dynamic (for a given PST file) and I am not familiar enough with pypff to advise you further on how to look them up.

Comment: @james-mcleod Thanks for the answer. Yes, entry_point values ​​are dynamic, but they are also stored in the same pst. How to find this place?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to find this using pypff (or libpff). My only knowledge of this comes from writing a Java parser for PST files. It's in the list of what Microsoft calls ["Calculated properties"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-pst/86dd69f7-8bef-48f3-abab-671b54e00976)

Comment: @james-mcleod Thanks for answer. I thought that the entry_type I needed was calculated dynamically when the file was modified and stored somewhere in separate branches of the object. You provided a link to "calculated value" - this is news to me. At the same time, having downloaded the entire document [MS-PST].pdf from the link, I did not find any mention of *StartWhole among calculated value. Please tell me, is *StartWhole a calculated object or stored in pst? If it is calculated, could you tell me which document established the rules for its calculation?Thank you.

Comment: It is the property ID which is calculated/dynamic, not the property value (dynamic in the sense that it can be different for every PST file, not that it changes after its initial definition). More info can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148

Comment: I'd suggest posting this question to the library developers at https://github.com/libyal/libpff/tree/main